# css - customize dropdown button on inputfield

Tags: html, css

I am required to make an input field that has an autocomplete functionality and they want a custom kind of button that shows that the input field is something different than just an input field.

but I can't seem to customize the class `-ms-expand` because all my css gets ignored. as you can see, it has `display:none;` but it still displays.

```css
.input, .input2{
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
  -moz-appearance:menulist;
}

.input::-ms-expand{
   display:none;
   color:green;
   background-color:red;
   border-left:1px solid black;
}
    
.input2::-ms-expand{
   float:left;
   color:red;
   background-color:green;
   border-right:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" class="input" />
<input id="input2" class="input2" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have another css File in the directory which oversteers the one you're editing. Did you check that?

Comment: yeah, i searched the whole solution for `::-ms-expand` and got only 1 result (this one)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are trying to attach styles to a class with pseudo element. You should in fact just style it normally using the class names.

```
.input {
  display: none;
}

.input2 {
  background: red;
}
```

Link for your reference: https://codepen.io/Harsh89/pen/VGbmVg

I would suggest to not use -ms-expand though, there are other alternatives.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-ms-expand

Comment: but this changes the background of the inputfield to red, which I don't want.. I only want that little "triangle arrow" to turn red

Comment: Got it. In that case, alas there is no other way because it is browser rendered. I have done it earlier by adding an image inside the input box or select box. That is much easier, simpler and preferred way of doing it.

Comment: yeah I wanted to do that too but I don't have an img of what my superiors want laying around haha. but right now I'm working on just making the input thinner and placing a div beside it to edit that as a button :P

Comment: haha work it out with your superiors. I would suggest a better option to use any icon which looks good. You can use fontawesome.

Comment: yeah apparently (this app's style is based on the main app) they also do what I am now doing in that app.. so apparently this is the way to dit it. And this question has become useless :P